# Segmentation Fault when trying to split string

Tags: c, string

for a larger program, I am trying to split a string after every n amount of characters. For example, ideally I should see something like this:

```
$ ./split
str = this is a test that I am doing. No need to panic. This is just a test.

=>this <=
=>is a <=
=>test <=
=>that <=
=>I am <=
=>doing<=
=>. No <=
=>need <=
=>to pa<=
=>nic. <=
=>This <=
=>is ju<=
=>st a <=
=>test.<=
```

Instead I am seeing the following output:

```
$ ./split
str = this is a test that I am doing. No need to panic. This is just a test.

Segmentation fault: 11
```

I have stared at this code continuously, but cannot for the life of me find the cause of the segmentation fault. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! Here is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **format(char *encoded_image, int encoded_image_size, int split) {
    int line_count = encoded_image_size / split + 1; /* One extra line for NULL */
    char **lines = malloc(sizeof(char *) * line_count);

    for(int iter = 0; iter < line_count - 1; ++iter) {
        lines[iter] = malloc(split);
        lines[iter] = memcpy(lines[iter], encoded_image[split * iter], split);
        printf("%s\n", lines[iter]);
    }

    lines[line_count] = NULL;
    return lines;
}

int main() {
    char *str = strdup("this is a test that I am doing. No need to panic. This is just a test.");
    printf("str = %s\n\n", str);
    char **lines = format(str, strlen(str), 5);

    for(int iter = 0; lines[iter] != NULL; ++iter) {
        printf("=>%s<=\n", lines[iter]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(there might be a spelling mistake in the ideal output, because I had to do it by hand). (fixed a mistake in the for loop pointed out in the comments below)

Comment: `for(int iter = 0; iter < line_count - 1; ++line_count)` ==> `for(int iter = 0; iter < line_count - 1; ++iter)`

Comment: Fixed. It still segfaults however

Comment: You do not terminate your strings. `lines[iter] = malloc(split + 1); lines[iter][split] = 0;`

Comment: Please do not correct the posted code following comments. Fix in your own code.

Comment: @WeatherVane I do...

Comment: @mch still segfaults

Comment: `lines[iter] = memcpy(lines[iter], encoded_image[split * iter], split);` ==> `memcpy(lines[iter], &encoded_image[split * iter], split);`

Comment: `lines[line_count] = NULL;` ==> `lines[iter] = NULL;` you have confused `iter` and `line_count` thouroughly.

Comment: Thank you mch! That did it. If you want to repost it as an answer I'll take it as the accepted one.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have not. That is supposed to be line_count there, as it is the last line... How do you expect to use a variable like iter when it is out of scope?

Comment: I'm not even sure how to respond to that. Mch fixed it, so I'm not sure where you're going with this.

Comment: OK, so the loop end condition is `iter < line_count-1` and after the loop you write `lines[line_count] = NULL`. So element `lines[line_count-1]` has not been written to.

Comment: the parameters to `memcpy()` are not correct, please read the man page for this function.   Regarding this line: `lines[iter] = memcpy(lines[iter], encoded_image[split * iter], split);` The encoded_image is a single int value, not some array.

Comment: In C, when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: strongly suggest paying attention to the 'type' of each argument to functions (see the appropriate man page for details)

Comment: the posted code has a fatal logic flaw when the length on the `str` is not a multiple of the 5.  As the integer division `encoded_image_size / split` rounds down, therefore the result should be rounded up, perhaps by: `(encoded_image_size+split) / split`  BTW: should not use 'magic' numbers (like 5) rather, give them meaningful names via an `enum` statement or `#define` statements.

Comment: this expression, in the call to `memcpy()` `encoded_image[split * iter]` should be: `&encoded_image[split * iter]`  <-- notice the addition of the `address of` operator `&`

Comment: in the call to `memcpy()`, the `split` parameter should be adjusted (when necessary) so characters past the end of the input `str` are not copied.

Comment: this line: `printf("%s\n", lines[iter]);` will result in undefined behavior because the value at each `lines[iter]` is NOT NUL terminated.

Comment: this line: `lines[iter] = malloc(split);` is not correct because it does not allocate enough memory to include a terminating NUL char.